# Connector shape in Crow's Foot Diagram in Visio 2013

Tags: database, erd, visio2013

How to connect one entity with its sub-entities? 
For example, I have an entity named PEOPLE. PEOPLE has two sub-entities, TEACHER and STUDENT. In old version Visio, there are a 'Category' shape and a 'Category to child' connector that allow to add branches. But Visio 2013 totally changed the shape in Crow's Foot Database Notation, and there is only one 'relationship' connector. How to connect child-entities to the parent-entity in Visio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation today.

I found a solution which might not be useful for you today, but may help others like me.

Solution is very simple, you just have to drag a new connector and connect with the main  connector.

[image]

If someone have a better answer please post here. Thanks